# How to used selected in dropdown list

Tags: php

i dont know exactly how i am supposed to explain my question. but i'll try my best. Im currently trying to make an update form. when user clicked on the edit icon they will be directed to the edit form and the value are carried. i used 'typeid' to carry the values. im having problem with my drop down. i used selected but the value duplicate.

[dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCQDL.png)

so im trying to solve this, but know idea how to solve it. i have to used php only and i am not an expert of php.

```
 if (isset($_GET['typeid'])) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicletype WHERE id_vehicleType=" . $_GET['typeid'];
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row['status_vehicleType']==1){
        $status = "Enabled";
    }
    else{
        $status = "Disabled";
    }
```

}

above are the typeid that i used to carry the values.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Choose Vehicle Type Status</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="status" required class="form-control" value="<? php if(isset($row['status_vehicleType'])){ echo $status; } ?>">
     <option value="">Select Vehicle Type</option>

     <option value=<?php echo $row['status_vehicleType']; ?> <?php if($_GET["typeid"]==$row['status_vehicleType']){ ?> selected <?php } ?> ><?php echo $status; ?></option>
       <option value="1">Enabled</option>
       <option value="0">Disabled</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code, (for testing set $_GET['typeid']=somevalue):

```
$row=array();
if (isset($_GET['typeid'])) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicletype WHERE id_vehicleType=" . $_GET['typeid'];
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}

<div class="form-group">
<label>Choose Vehicle Type Status</label>
<select class="form-control" name="status" required class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select Vehicle Type</option>
   <option value="1" <?php if($row['status_vehicleType']==1){?>selected<?php }?>>Enabled</option>
   <option value="0" <?php if($row['status_vehicleType']==0){?>selected<?php }?>>Disabled</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i tried to use your solutions but it gave me undefined variable row

Comment: $row is the variable from $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);. if html & sql code is on diff pages then from sql page you have to return that $row variable & pass to the html page

Comment: html and sql are on the same page..the sql code is on top of the page. dont know why it say undefined variable.

Comment: on top of query add line : $row=array();

Comment: $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);, i already used this one. before i click on the update button, there is no error. the error only occur after i clicked the update button.

Comment: error comes because the $row variable declare inside the foreach loop.. the scope of $row is only limited to foreach so that it shows error.. to avoid error you have to initialise that $row outside the foreach

Comment: how do i do that? im sorry..have no idea right now.

Comment: it worked..thanks. do u mind explained to me about this? i need to learn about this, or do u know where i can get information related about this?

Comment: the variable scope is basic concept in every programming language. In this example you wont declare the $row variable & you try to access it out side their scope so that it shows error.

Comment: after several testing, i got undefined index for the status_vehicleType. why is that?

Comment: when the type id is not set that time if condition  wont get execute so that array wont contain the 'status_vehicleType' key... to remove this error just set if condition like :  if(isset($row['status_vehicleType']) && $row['status_vehicleType']==1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple answer for this question

if you have any other questions freely ask me  thanks

```
   <?php

function selected($x, $y) {

    if ($x == $y) {
        return " selected";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}


     $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicletype WHERE id_vehicleType=" . $_GET['typeid'];
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

     $q_status = $row['status_vehicleType'] ;

    ?>
     <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label text-inverse" for="name">Status</label>
                                                <select  class="form-control" name="q_status" id="q_status" required=""    autocomplete="off" >
                                                   <option value="1"  <?php echo selected($q_status,"1");?> >Enabled</option>
                                                   <option value="0"  <?php echo selected($q_status,"0");?>  >Disabled</option>
                                                </select>
                                             </div>
```

Comment: fatal error : uncaught error : call to undefined function selected()

Comment: yup..its the selected function

Comment: here function


function selected($x, $y) {

    if ($x == $y) {
        return " selected";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}